# Django Query - where start = end

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

in models i have start and end date.
How to get all element where start and end date are diffrents.

```
>>> Entry.objects.exclude(start = end)
>>> NameError: name 'end' is not defined
```

I have no idea please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model

> In the examples given so far, we have constructed filters that compare the value of a model field with a constant. But what if you want to compare the value of a model field with another field on the same model?
>
> Django provides the F() object to allow such comparisons. Instances of F() act as a reference to a model field within a query. These references can then be used in query filters to compare the values of two different fields on the same model instance.

For your case, the following should work.

```
from django.db.models import F
Entry.objects.exclude(start=F('end'))
```